# Does Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 with GIT have any access logging

Tags: git, logging, tfs, tfs-2015

We have a onsite installation of Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 1 and are using GIT for version control. Is there any way to log all access to the GIT repos?

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in access logging in Team Foundation Server. Generally you need to accept that when a user has access, he may have accessed the data.

TFS does internally keep a (temporary) log of all actions through the Command (`tbl_Command`) table in the TFS databases, which is also accessible through the Activity Log page:

```
http://server:port/tfs/_oi
```

Unfortunately, this data is only kept for 14 days by default, so unless you've archived the data and extracted the information you wanted, there is no way to  retroactively piece together the logs.

With the distributed nature of Git, it's also important to remember that every Git repository is a potential source of all the history in the central repository. This includes access through a network share or even local access to a local git repository of another user. There will never be a way for the central server to log these other types of access.

As to writes, TFS keeps full logs on every change to each git repository through the nature of Git itself. As long as users do not have Force Push permission (by default only Project Admins have that) you can trust the history to have logged all changes that were ever pushed to the server.

Some background details on the Operational Insights page:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2013/03/30/how-to-see-activity-and-job-history-in-tfs-2012/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2013/02/13/tfs2012-new-tools-for-tfs-administrators/

Comment: Nice, didn't know that! Source?

Comment: @legends which part would you like a source for? Most of this is internal only and you'll only find references to it in blog posts, not in official documentation.

Comment: Didn't know about this Activity log page. Thanks for the info.